# MongoMapper with Padrino Forms Select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, sinatra, mongomapper, padrino

I am using mongomapper inorder to associate 2 models together in a one-to-many relationship.

I want to show the ids of one model into the other models in the padrino admin section.

I am trying to use the <%= f.select %> of padrino forms. to mimic what in rails would be somthing like this with activerecord

Please advice on the f.select syntax for padrino's form.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that <%f.select_block :model_attr, :options => Model.all %> do the trick.

Comment: thanks ,that kind of works but it returns somehing like <#survey id:/// > instead of the id => name

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  <% @options = Survey.where(:active => 1) %>
  <%= f.select :survey_id, :collection => @options , :fields  => [:name, :id] %>
```

The fields parameter will determine what goes in the value and what in the label